# How to filter report at side bar in Openerp

Tags: odoo

i have different report for different purposes, i created 4 different transaction different menu with stock.picking object

1. Incoming transaction
2. Delivery transaction
3. Incoming return transaction
4. Delivery return transaction

each of these transaction has different layout report. i created 4 reports on "Low Level Objects - Actions - Report" but all displayed on each menu transaction is there anyway how i can filter my report to display at these transaction?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter report to show in different stock.picking menu then you have to specify model as shown below, 
if you want to show report in Incoming Shipment menu then you have to pass model='stock.picking.in', 
and if delivery order then specify model="stock.picking.out"

```
<report id="report_picking_list_in" **model="stock.picking.in"** name="stock.picking.list.in" string="Receipt Slip" rml="stock/report/picking.rml"/>

<report id="report_picking_list_out" ***model="stock.picking.out"*** name="stock.picking.list.out" string="Delivery Slip" rml="stock/report/picking.rml"/>
```

Hope this help

Comment: but the issue right now is the 4 menu i had are using stock.picking object. And i believe model on ir.action.report.xml is refer to ir.model which is the objects we used and it'll auto display it on left side bar.

Answer (score 0):

I've got solution,

Inherit the object 'stock.picking', overwrite the function **field_view_get** of the model to which the server action belong, you an see that there is a key called "**toolbar**" in the fields_view_get result. This key contains all the details regarding the action in the "Print" and "More" dropdown in web client. So if you remove the server action from here, that server action wont be listed in the "More" dropdown or Sidebar anymore.